# Mysql date range does not return correct range

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
select date_format(fee_month, '%b-%Y') from bb_fee_info where 
date_format(`FEE_MONTH`,'%b-%Y') >= 'Apr-2016' 
and date_format(`fee_month`, '%b-%Y') <= 'Apr-2017'
```

As per my understanding above statement should return from April-2016 to April-2017 but it only returns `April-2017` records why is that ?

FYI in my Table `fee_month` stored as `date` data type and for example, for April month records all my `fee_month` will be stored as `2017-04-01`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try comparing the `date`s directly instead, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fee_month, '%b-%Y') 
FROM bb_fee_info 
WHERE fee_month BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2017-04-01';
```

If you can't change the argument type/format then you can convert it into `date` using `STR_TO_DATE` and do the comparison, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fee_month, '%b-%Y') 
FROM bb_fee_info 
WHERE fee_month BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', 'Apr-2016'),'%d-%M-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', 'Apr-2017'),'%d-%M-%Y')
```

Comment: But I want equals part

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive of start and end dates. Do you have `time` component as well, with dates?

Comment: No time component, but your solution is working fine, but why my query acting weird ?

Comment: Try replacing `%b` with `%M`?

Comment: @Babel This (the first suggestion) is a much smarter solution as it allows the use of indexes

Comment: @DarshanMehta  I think`%M` is for full month name then how that matches when we do `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', 'Apr-2016'),'%d-%M-%Y')` is not that supposed to be `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', 'Apr-2016'),'%d-%b-%Y')`  this ?

Comment: @Babel it might be because it is comparing the `String` literally instead of dates and hence, it's not returning the expected result. Could you try removing either of `>=` and `<=` and see which one breaks it?

Comment: It seems to be matching both, here is the SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9deb/54/0

Comment: @DarshanMehtan yes it is matching ,,.. I followed conversion using this  [link](http://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-073.html) would it be different from one mysql version to another ?

Comment: Well, don't know it it's any different. However, I would always recommend following MySQL's own page : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format